# Implement own system call

Tags: linux-kernel

What is the step by step procedure to implement our own system call that does some specific tasks like printing some message or adding two real numbers ? I have found some guideline while searching it in google, but those are all for 32-bit machine. What is the approach for 64-bit machine ?

Comment: Steps for implementing a system call doesn't change from architecture to architecture. And why would you bother implementing a system call to add two real numbers? You can see include/linux/syscalls.h and definition of each functions declared there to see how to implement one of your own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to read ["Implementing a System Call"](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/).

Despite the fact that this howto is pretty old it is still useful. In recent kernel you can find syscall table in `arch/x86/syscalls`.